# How do I create a indefinitely long plot range?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a graph for excel that takes data from a extending plot range, and I'm trying to use define a name with the range and use it as a legend entry, which doesn't work.

Formula for name I used.
=OFFSET(Sheet2!A2, 0, 0, COUNTA (Sheet2!A:A) - 1)

[the name + range formula I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f3mC.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrssR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to find a way around Offset. It's a volatile function and using Index is almost always better. It looks like you're trying to create a range that's dynamic... so this should work:

(Updated with absolute references)

`=Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A),1)`

[See sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j9JKfUTQYn1B5kRqkqGmOM16a7czX8S5UodJxHTSozo/edit#gid=0) using it in a sum function. You'd have to use that for the named range, but just a copy paste.

Comment: sorry, but it gave me a error when I put it in a series: "there's a error in the formula you entered."

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag absolute reference... I'll fix...

Comment: and now excel gives me "there's a problem with this formula" when I use it in a series and "there's a error in the formula you entered" when I put it into a name and use the name in a data series.

I hate excel.